# How to properly monitor ELB latency on AWS using Grafana?

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to monitor Latency on ElasticBeanstalk environment using Grafana.

I get some things to work, and some things do not provide any information.

I am using "CloudWatch" data source.

There is ELB and ApplicationELB.
The ApplicationELB does not offer Latency metric. In fact, every metric I select here will result with "no data".

When I configure monitoring on AWS, I get this following graph:

[image: AWS Graph]

I am able to query for Latency on a region using Grafana and I do get some correlation

[image: Grafana Graph]

As you can see around 13:50 some requests timed-out. But it is also obvious Grafana is showing additional information from other environments which I would like to ignore.

My query currently looks like this:

[image: Grafana Query]

Which I know is too broad, but I do not know how to refine.

- I tried using "InstanceName" as dimension, but it is not clear to me which ELB I should look for, and seems to me like ApplicationELB should be what I am looking for, but that one does not offer Latency and does not provide any data either way.
- Using AvailabilityZone does not help, and that's the only other option for dimension (other than InstanceName).

I need a way to refine the query so I see the same result in AWS and Grafana.
A clarification about ApplicationELB and ELB would be great also!

Comment: It is not clear what a how did you use? Cloudwatch datasource? It will be good if you can add a query to your question?

Comment: @JanGaraj, well that's just because I have no clue :D . I had some progress, so I added details on my question, plus focused it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Application ELB vs ELB: they are just different types of load balancers provided by AWS https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/ - I'm not sure which one is used by ElasticBeanstalk.

You need to add dimension to filter your metrics. Some metrics may need multiple dimensions for correct filtering. Available dimensions are available in the docs. For example `LoadBalancerName` is a correct dimension for `AWS/ELB` namespace: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html

I recommend to use existing published AWS dashboard(s) (https://github.com/monitoringartist/grafana-aws-cloudwatch-dashboards - I'm the author) and then just customize them for your needs.